# Is there a way to disable the mysql -- comment syntax?

Tags: mysql, security

I recently had to investigate an SQL incursion and noticed how -- is a great help for an attacker. Considering it's not a very useful instrument in many web environments, but seems to add to the damage potential of such vulnerabilities, why not disable it? I couldn't find a way, hence the question.

Comment: Parameterized queries are a better way to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: what application layer are you using?

Comment: SQL comments are not your problem, SQL injection is. So fix the latter.

Comment: Konfuzius says: There will be bad code. If there wasn't, there would be no exploits. Even if a feature does not pose a threat in itself, if it serves as nothing but an aid to attackers, there should be a way to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to disable SQL comment parsing.

The correct solution is to ensure your application does not allow it to occur by always escaping user input, or better yet by using parametrised queries of some kind whether directly through the MySQL server API or through a user library that does it client-side.

Disabling comments may help a little, but it is very easy to do SQL injection without them, they can simply write the start of another complete query instead of commenting out the remainder of the statement.

If that is not practical for some reason, you may be able to consider the MySQL Enterprise Firewall (this is a commercial product and not open source) which allows you to setup a query whitelist:
https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/firewall.html